# How to create environment variable for existing power apps?

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have already created power app connected with sharepoint lists. I need to deploy this app to dev, test and prod environments. I turned on the "automatically create environment variables when adding data source" from settings but it doesn't create variables for existing data sources. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Try removing the existing data sources and re-create those using environmental variables. Check: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Pro-Dev-ISV/Adding-environment-variable-to-canvas-app/td-p/1416626. Let me know if this works for you.